# Laravel Query Builder: Caching a list result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

It's possible to cache query result like so:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();
```

But how do I cache a list result. This doesn't work:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title'); // Works, but not cached.
$roles = DB::table('roles')->remember(10)->lists('title'); // Not working.
```

Error thrown:

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::remember()` was removed in laravel 5+, you can use this instead:

```
$roles = Cache::remember('roles', 10, function() {
    return DB::table('roles')->lists('title');
});
```

I hope this will help you.